# Spring project failed to start: Jwt depency is not imported

Tags: spring, maven, jwt, classloader

I am working within a group project, after working on my local branch ( and every thing were fine) I tried to get the last version of the project and merged it with my local branch. The project is compiling fine, but when starting it: I have

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authRestService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'contextService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contextServiceImpl': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [fr.project.ui.components.services.core.ContextUiServiceImpl] from ClassLoader [ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ROOT
delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@12843fce
]
2019-09-11 13:22:07.688 [NS5] [] [DESKTOP-6JB7LEQ] [ERROR] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext:312 -
                [:] [] [/] - Context initialization failed

>     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [fr.project.ui.components.services.core.ContextServiceImpl] from
> ClassLoader [ParallelWebappClassLoader   context: ROOT   delegate:
> false
>     ----------> Parent Classloader: java.net.URLClassLoader@12843fce ]    at
> org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:507)
>   at
> org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:404)
>   at
> org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:389)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:248)
>   ... 72 common frames omitted Caused by:
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/auth0/jwt/algorithms/Algorithm    at
> java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
> java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)    at
> java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)   at
> org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:489)
>   ... 75 common frames omitted Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1308)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1136)
>   ... 79 common frames omitted
```

I added the version 3.3.0 of auth0-jwt on the pom.xml of the project like all the other dependencies.
PS: I tried to delete the depencies for the .m2 repostiroy folder, clear cache reimoprt ..
Nothing seems to work.

My question is: does the error really means that a jwt depency is missing, or it s the project itself who is not able to create the bean due to context issue

When I delete all dependencies and reimport the jwt: is added in the external libraries as a jar and not a librarie

like it is shown at the picture 
[image]

Thank You

Comment: Seems like class are not in the final jar. Can you check the jar built as a zip (which is not running) if the class is in there? Are you creating a fat-jar? Did you add the dependency with compile scope?

Comment: thank you @helospark for your response, yes the algrithm class is in java-jwt jar ( when I check the zip it exists) but I edited my post of the picture of how maven imports  the dependencies

Comment: What I meant was that the jar you have built (with Maven) contains it?

Comment: Can we see you pom.xml file ?